# manipulating multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array. Since the value of the string "volvo" is present twice, I want to combine those keys. Here's the source array:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 17
        )

)
```

and I'd like to convert it to this one:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Volvo
            [1] => 39
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BMW
            [1] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Saab
            [1] => 5
        )
)
```

Comment: <?php

 function getSummary($data){
  $result = array();
  foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
   $temp = $row;
   if(!in_array($temp, $data))
    array_push($result, $temp);
   else
    $result[$key][1] += $temp[1];

  return $result;
 }
 
 $data = array ( array("Volvo",22), array("BMW",15), array("Saab",5), array("Volvo",17) );
 print("<pre>");
 print_r(getsummary($data));
 print("</pre>");

Comment: sorry im not used to multidimensional array. :) thnx

Comment: @hassan thnx for the response

Comment: Please reformulate your question. Add the PHP code used to produce this output in the question. After that explain what you expect as output. So everyone will understand what you have done and will try to fix your code. Otherwise you will continue to be down-voted. This may help: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would make more sense to return an associated array, that way you can do `$arr["volvo"]`, if you're fine with an associated array, just remove the second `foreach` loop.

If not, this will get the correct output:

```
<?php

$arr = Array (
    Array (
        "Volvo",
        22
    ),
    Array (
        "BMW",
        15
    ),
    Array (
        "Saab",
        5
    ),
    Array (
        "Volvo",
        17
    )
);

$tmpNewArr = Array();
foreach ($arr as $ele) {
    if (!isset($arr[$ele[0]])) {
        $tmpNewArr[$ele[0]] = 0;
    }
    $tmpNewArr[$ele[0]] += $ele[1];
}
$newArr = [];
foreach ($tmpNewArr as $key => $ele) {
    array_push($newArr,[$key,$ele]);
}

var_dump($newArr);

?>
```

Here's an eval.in:

https://eval.in/766340

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyValueCars = [];
foreach($cars as $car){
   $brand = $car[0];
   $total = $car[1];
   if(!isset($keyValueCars[$brand])){
       $keyValueCars[$brand] = total; 
   }
   else{
       $keyValueCars[$brand] += total; 
   }
}
```

Comment: thnx for answering the question. seems function isset is more preferable than using in_array ( i was speaking on php). thnx @r4ccoon

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
array_unique(Your_array, SORT_REGULAR);
```